# Copy only constraint Keys from one database to another in pgAdmin

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin-4

I have two servers (and two databases each one from a server on pgAdmin):

The first server is for testing and the second one is the real server that the client will work on it.

The two databases have same tables: 9 tables on the first one and the same 9 tables on the second one.

But on the test server, I have constraint keys (Check, foreign, unique, not null) that I have tested and ready to be deployed on the server 2.

How i can copy only those constraints?

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to do this is to use a command-line pg_dump tool, which is included in all PostgreSQL installations.

- Create a backup of the target database:
  `$ pg_dump -h /var/run/postgresql/ -d prod -Fd -f prod.pg_dump`
- Create a backup of the source database schema:
  `$ pg_dump -h /var/run/postgresql/ -d test --section=pre-data --section=post_data -Fd -f test_schema.pg_dump`
- Drop the target database:
  `postgres=# drop database prod;`
- Recreate empty target database:
  `postgres=# create database prod;`
- Import to the target database:

  - test table definitions:
    `$ pg_restore -d prod --section=pre-data test_schema.pg_dump`
  - prod data:
    `$ pg_restore -d prod --section=data prod.pg_dump`
  - test constraints and indexes:
    `$ pg_restore -d prod --section=post-data test_schema.pg_dump`
- Analyze the target database:
  `prod=> analyze;`

---

This can be optimized with parallel restore with proper usage of `pg_restore -j`.

---

You might consider a proper [schema change management solution](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Change_management_tools_and_techniques) for the future.

Comment: The problem is that the psql is not running on my pc. I don't know why.

Comment: This is something you should fix to be able to do administrative tasks on your database effectively. Maybe search for an error message on [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/) or try to describe your problem and ask for help there.